why does it give me this $route variable error?
I'm trying to define a variable. However, I get "undefined variable $route" as an error message. What am I doing wrong?
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use  App\Http\Controllers\PublicController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ArticleController;

Route::get('/', [PublicController::class, 'homepage']) ->name('homepage');
Route::post('/article/store' , [ArticleController::class , 'store']) -> name ('article.store');
Route::get('/article/create' , [ArticleController::class , 'create']) -> name ('article.create');
Route::get('/article/index' , [ArticleController::class , 'index']) ->name ('article.index');
Route::get('/article/show/{article}' , [ArticleController::class , 'show'])->name('article.show');
Route::get('/article/category/{category}' , [ArticleController::class, 'byCategory'])->name('article.byCategory');

enter image description here
above is the code of our routes. what did we do wrong?
